# How to add image background in only one widget

Tags: css, wordpress

I want to add image background in only one widget. For example, like this homepage on website: http://www.goldenrama.com/. For each widget, this is filling in different background. I don't know to modify CSS and html.

I am using wordpress with BookYourTravel theme.

I'll be lucky if i get solution of this problem.

Regards,
Erwan

Comment: could you provide a link to the page you are working on? Could you also explain what exactly you are reffering to in the page you are linking.

Comment: Sorry, i have not a domain url, i just designed website.
Exactly i want to filling in background on every section content. You can see the website that i was linking in the line of Golden Rama Highlights, Relaxing Holidays, and Holidays, by Golden Rama. Every section of those parts have different background. Could you help me to give any advice please.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

G'day Erwan,

To alter just one particular widget, use the firefox inspect element tool:
1. Right click on the widget
2. Go to inspect element

You will then see that each widget has a unique id. For example when I inspect a widget on one of my clients sites I get:

In this case the id is "wpp-2"

So then to add a background image you would just do this via CSS as follows:

```
#wpp-2 {
background-image: url('images/foo.jpg');
}
```